# Getting Cached JSON object to appear when ionic app is offline

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following AngularJS controller setup to grab information from an outside API. The problem is there could be a situation where the mobile device does not have or has a terrible internet connection. I'm using cordovaNetwork to see if the device is online but it appears to not be working.

I am getting the following error in console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Can someone tell me what I'm missing:

```
    .controller('LennoxProductCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaNetwork) {

  if($cordovaNetwork.isOnline()) {

    $scope.loading = true;                
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.lennox.com/v1/hSPgMEU/categories",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.$apply(function() {
              console.log(data.Category);
                $scope.categories = data.Category;
            });
            localStorage.setItem("lennoxProducts", JSON.stringify(data.Category));
        },
        error: function (data) {

          if(localStorage.getItem("lennoxProducts") !== undefined) {
              $scope.categories = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lennoxProducts"));
          } 
          $scope.loading = false;

        }            
    });

  } else {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Error',
      content: 'Check Your Network Connection'
    });
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

cordovaNetwork apparently always throws errors when viewed using web developer tools, however it appears to be working when app is built and ran on a device.

Comment: Not only $cordovaNetwork but almost all cordova plugins. By the way you should use ionic.native in flavour of ng-cordova